# mvn integration-test fails on Javassist error

Tags: maven, grails

When running mvn integration-test Grails gives Javassist errors.

I filed a bug (with an example app) here:
https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11809

```
2014-10-30 11:01:07,295 -0400 [main] ERROR BasicLazyInitializer:213 - Javassist Enhancement   failed: my.company.Author
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: hasProperty for class: groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl
at _GrailsTest$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsTest.groovy:102)
at TestApp$_run_closure1.doCall(TestApp.groovy:32)
at org.grails.launcher.GrailsLauncher.launch(GrailsLauncher.java:144)
at org.grails.maven.plugin.tools.DefaultGrailsRuntime.run(DefaultGrailsRuntime.java:18)
at org.grails.maven.plugin.AbstractGrailsMojo.runGrails(AbstractGrailsMojo.java:372)
at org.grails.maven.plugin.MvnFunctionalTestMojo.execute(MvnFunctionalTestMojo.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Comment: I think I found the issue.  The grails create-pom creates a pom.xml file that has cache 1.1.7.  You need cache 1.1.8

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments:

> I think I found the issue. The grails create-pom creates a pom.xml
>   file that has cache 1.1.7. You need cache 1.1.8 –  Tom Gullo Dec 5 '14
>   at 16:05